# Populate data from a Google Form survey into new tab, using template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a sheet with survey results from a Google Form (26 responses).  I have succeeded in getting the script to open a new tab with the name I specified from that survey tab.  But the new tab is currently blank, so how can I get it to import that row of data into that tab that it just made?  This is the script that is working, but I am not sure what/how to integrate the piece that tells it to import the row of data.

```
function wa13477102() {

  // set up the spreadsheet and establish the current sheet with a new tab named after the survey inquirer name
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get the name of the current sheet - so that you don't accidentally try and name the new sheet with the same name.
  var oldName = sheet.getName();

  // get the values from Cell B2 and C2
  // Note for the date in Cell C2 we use "getDisplayValue()" for a WYSIWYG value.

  var myday = sheet.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();


  // get the new name just by joining the two; there are lots of other ways to do this; you can search on Stackoverflow
  var newName = myday;

  // logic 
  // 1) if the length of the newname is grater than zero - that means there IS a value for newname; it's not just a blank.
  // AND
  // 2) the new name isn't the same as the old name.
  if (newName.toString().length > 0 && newName !== oldName) {

    // insert a new sheet and name it with your newname.
    ss.insertSheet(newName);
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what the script should do.

Comment: What row of data are you talking about when you say `I am not sure what/how to integrate the piece that tells it to import the row of data.`?

Comment: If you with to import the data that gets submitted to the sheet that form is linked to then consider using the onFormSubmit trigger for a spreadsheet.  The event object for that trigger is discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?hl=en#form-submit)

Comment: Ruben, the script should take the data from the survey (its in tab 1, having been automatically imported from the google form) into the new tab (which the script above successfully created), each time a new row appears because of a new form submission.  I think there is a way to do it using a template so the data is organized upon its importation into the new tab for that row of data from tab 1.

Comment: Cooper, the new row of data with each new submission of the google form as it imports.  See my response to Ruben to clarify. Each new submission makes its own tab and that tab should have the data from that row (in tab one where the form data imported to) which triggered it.

Answer (score 0):

### What you are looking for is a [form submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) trigger

This trigger gives you access to e.g. the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) `values`.

In other words:

**If you [bind your function to the installable `form submit` trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), each time a new form response is submitted, you will be able to access the respective data and copy it to another tab as desired.**

Sample:

```js
function bindMeOnFormuSubmitTrigger(event) {
// YOUR OLD CODE
  // set up the spreadsheet and establish the current sheet with a new tab named after the survey inquirer name
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // get the name of the current sheet - so that you don't accidentally try and name the new sheet with the same name.
  var oldName = sheet.getName();

  // get the values from Cell B2 and C2
  // Note for the date in Cell C2 we use "getDisplayValue()" for a WYSIWYG value.

  var myday = sheet.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue();


  // get the new name just by joining the two; there are lots of other ways to do this; you can search on Stackoverflow
  var newName = myday;

  // logic 
  // 1) if the length of the newname is grater than zero - that means there IS a value for newname; it's not just a blank.
  // AND
  // 2) the new name isn't the same as the old name.
  if (newName.toString().length > 0 && newName !== oldName) {

    // insert a new sheet and name it with your newname.
    ss.insertSheet(newName);
  }


//HERE COMES THE ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONALITY

  var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(newName);
  var values = event.values;
  newSheet.appendRow(values);

}
```